# How to change IP and country location selenium python that makes different IP with different country every time the script run?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, python-requests

I have to change my IP and my location every time I run selenium python script

for example

first run :  IP is X and location is A

second run:  IP is Y and location is B and so on

Comment: If you are in Europe, restarting your router will most likely give you a new global IP. The only way to change your location, would be to connect to an external server somewhere else in the world and use it as a proxy - vpn.

Comment: I am in Egypt, so how can i connect external server ?

Comment: This is a networking question and not related to selenium or python. You will need to either rent VPS's in different parts of the world or utilize VPNs and/or proxies to have your networking activity routed differently.